# warning: Cannot send message. websocket is not available

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Running my game in Unity, from the same query, sometimes it takes about 90sec-120secs to obtain data from RTDB. When it happens, I sometimes get this

```
Cannot send message.  websocket is not available
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.YjzkX82xZ8/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseLogger.cs:92)
Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessage(LogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BahqeQHBdV/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/LogUtil.cs:68)
Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessageFromCallback(LogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BahqeQHBdV/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/LogUtil.cs:76)
Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:PollCallbacks()
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BahqeQHBdV/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/AppUtil.cs:32)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.BahqeQHBdV/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseAppUtils.cs:33)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.YjzkX82xZ8/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseHandler.cs:205)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.YjzkX82xZ8/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseMonoBehaviour.cs:45)
```

- I suspected the Win Firewall but it would be constantly blocked then.
- I did tracert myApp.firebaseio.com during the lagging and it completed 
  successuflly within 100ms.

Looking around, I could not find anything useful. Any ideas?

Comment: Won't be easy to answer. Can you ensure that a connection to the server can be made? E.g is there a `traceroute` to the destination when the issue occurs. If not your connection in unstable. It might be the realtime db dropping your connection or the websocket might be in use by something else

Comment: Yes a connection can be made since the results are finally coming if I wait 2 mins. When it does, I get about 3x the warning message all at once just before I get the DB callback with results. I did tracert myApp.firebaseio.com during the lagging and it completed successuflly within 100ms. How can I watch my websocket connection? I suspected the Win Firewall but it would be constantly blocked then. –

Comment: Check TCP View (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview). It is still not really solvable beside best guessing as there is not enough data to anlayze your problem. TCP View allows to see whether there is already something else bound on the given TCP port. There might be an implementation issue where a previous connection on the same port is held by something else and it timeouts after a period allowing your current connection to be made. This might be a bug in your code or the issue might be something completely different.

Comment: tcp view showed me Unity is using about a dozen connections, one of them with googleusercontent.com but I could'nt see any port conflict. Auth is connecting fine, RTDB initializes OK but but when it comes to get or send data, huge 2-4 mins lags come in. I revised my code to find that retiring dbRootRref.KeepSynced(true);  did the trick. Dunno why. Thanks for your time Samuel

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was comment out the line

```
dbRootRref.KeepSynced(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this warning spamming 999+ times a second after stopping my test play. It happened a bit randomly, the only change I noticed was a significant delay in access to my server on that day. I believe that it may come from the Firebase thread or a delayed response due to connection issues.

Either way, the only way to stop the spamming for me was to close and re-open Unity.